# GAEJ: loading external XML

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine

What is the simpliest way to load an external xml within Google App Engine framework?

I tried what Google advises:

```
URL url = new URL("http://mydomain.com/data.xml");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
// ...
}
reader.close();
```

But it doesn't work.

it gives **`line = null`**

Comment: "It gives line=null" when? Immediately? After reading some lines? Are you sure the server isn't just returning an empty response body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for help. It was an inappropriate panic by me caused by my noobnes in Java.
It was handled this way.
Sorry for disturing.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
            xmlResponce = xmlResponce.concat(line);

}

reader.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

To be able to get items from other web sites you are going to need the [URLFetch service](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/).
Have you tried getting the page in a browser ? Have you tried a sample standalone program ? You also do not specify if you are working in debug mode or on GAE server. Are you behind a firewall ?

Comment: actually the OP is using the URLFetch service